# QWidgetAction checked state not changing when using setDefaultWidget to a QCheckBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a menu with a checkable list.  To prevent the menu from closing when the action is clicked, I'm setting the DefaultWidget to be a QCheckBox.  The problem is when I'm trying to get isClicked from the action - it doesn't seem to be synced to the checkbox.  How do I get the value of the action to change when the checkbox is clicked?

```
tool_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()

check_box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(menu)
check_box.setText("abc")
check_box.setChecked(True)
action_button = QtWidgets.QWidgetAction(menu)
action_button.setDefaultWidget(check_box)

menu.addAction(action_button)
tool_button.setMenu(menu)

print(check_box.text()) # returns abc
print(check_box.isChecked()) # returns True
print(action_button.isChecked()) # returns False - it's not picking up the values from check_box
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since QWidgetAction acts as some sort of container for *any* kind of widget, it has no way to know if its `defaultWidget` could even have any support for a bool state like "isChecked", so you have to provide it.

The simplest way is to subclass a specific QWidgetAction class for that action, and override its `isChecked()` method so that it returns the checked value based on its default widget.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class CheckableWidgetAction(QtWidgets.QWidgetAction):
    def setDefaultWidget(self, widget):
        super().setDefaultWidget(widget)
        try:
            # if the widget has the toggled signal, connect that signal to the
            # triggered signal
            widget.toggled.connect(self.triggered)
        except:
            pass

    def isChecked(self):
        try:
            return self.defaultWidget().isChecked()
        except:
            # failsafe, in case no default widget has been set or the provided
            # widget doesn't have a "checked" property
            return super().isChecked()


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        tool_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        layout.addWidget(tool_button)
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()

        check_box = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(menu)
        check_box.setText("abc")
        check_box.setChecked(True)
        self.action_button = CheckableWidgetAction(menu)
        self.action_button.setDefaultWidget(check_box)
        self.action_button.triggered.connect(self.action_triggered)

        menu.addAction(self.action_button)
        tool_button.setMenu(menu)

        controlButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('is checked?')
        layout.addWidget(controlButton)
        controlButton.clicked.connect(self.is_checked)

    def is_checked(self):
        print('checked is {}'.format(self.action_button.isChecked()))

    def action_triggered(self, state):
        print('triggered {}'.format(state))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    a = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: yes, this is what I did (create a subclass of QWidgetAction) but thought there would be a simpler way.

Comment: @jole5646 QWidgetAction can be used used for any kind of widget, so it cannot foresee what those widgets can or cannot do. For example, the QCheckBox could be a tristate, and that would be incompatible (or possibly incoherent) with the actual action checked state.